# Can a router use a PC's internet connection without an ISP?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, tethering

There's an "xfinity" WiFi hotspot nearby which I connect to with my smartphone, which I then usb-tether to my PC.

**I want to know if it's possible to set up a router to use the internet connection on this PC (supplied by my phone), to supply internet access to connected devices?**

Perhaps this can be done by assigning the PC a static IP, then setting that IP as a proxy at the router level? (Not sure if that's even possible.)

Reasons why I want to do this: to set up a VPN on the router, let friends be able to connect to my "own" WiFi network without me having to give them my xfinity password, etc.

Comment: The router would have to be dual-band to do what you describe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. The steps are:

1) Enable Internet Connection Sharing on the PC to share the wireless Internet to clients on its Ethernet port.

2) Connect the PC's Ethernet port to the router's WAN port.

Alternatively:

1) Enable Internet Connection Sharing on the PC to share the wireless Internet to clients on its Ethernet port.

2) Disable the router's DHCP server.

3) Configure the router's to obtain its LAN IP using DHCP.

4) Connect the PC's Ethernet port to one of the router's LAN ports.

Comment: It seems ICS isn't working? Android hosts the gateway/DHCP on 192.168.42.139. I disabled DHCP on the router and set its static IP to 192.168.42.100. When I turn on ICS on the Android NIC, Windows automatically overwrites the router NIC's TCP settings, setting a static IP of 192.168.137.1 and a blank default gateway. I manually change the IP to 192.168.42.200 (and set the gateway IP to .139). At this point, I can reach the router's login page at 192.168.42.200, but it's listed as "Unidentified network" and when I connect a laptop to the router's WiFi network, no internet access.

Comment: However, bridging the router and Android NICs does work. But then the router port forwarding/firewall/etc settings appear not to be in effect, I assume cause that's being handled by the gateway (Android)? That's workable for me but I'm still curious why ICS isn't sharing the connection... Thanks for the help!

Comment: First comment contained a typo: "I can reach the router's login page at 192.168.42.200..." should be 192.168.42.100.

Comment: Sorry for the endless comments... I forgot to give some context. My router (NETGEAR C6300) just has 4 Ethernet sockets and a female F-connector so I went with the "alternative" steps. Also, the router admin console forces me to set a static IP, so I couldn't follow step 3. Perhaps that's why it's not getting the gateway configuration from the DHCP server on Android? Cause it's not reaching out to the DHCP in the first place?

Comment: Why are you turning on ICS on the Android NIC? That's not where you're trying to share.

Comment: I was confusing the NICs with the external devices, and figured since the Android phone is providing internet to the PC, it was the Android NIC whose "internet connection" needed to be "shared" with the router NIC. It just dawned on me it's the "PC" whose internet connection (via Android NIC) is being shared with the target NIC, right? Duh.

Comment: I tried reversing it. Once again, Windows overwrites the static TCP settings for the non-shared NIC, this time the Android NIC. Android is hard-coded to host the gateway on 192.168.42.129 so I went in and manually changed the static IP to x.x.42.1 and set the gateway to x.x.42.129. When I did that, "IPv4 Connectivity" went from "No network access" to "Internet", but there's no internet access... According to ipconfig, the Android NIC has two IPv4 addresses now, x.x.42.1, and x.x.137.1. :( ICS seems to like x.x.137, but Android insists on using x.x.42. Meh.